# nvcc fatal : Unknown option '--threads'

Tags: cmake, cuda, gpu, nvidia

I have installed CUDA-11.3 and NVIDIA Driver Version 465, CMAKE version 3.16.3.
I was trying to compile samples included in th toolkit to verify the installation but getting the following error.

```
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/user/NVIDIA_CUDA-11.3_Samples/0_Simple/simpleSeparateCompilation'
/usr/local/cuda/bin/nvcc -ccbin g++ -I../../common/inc  -m64    -dc --threads 0 -gencode arch=compute_35,code=sm_35 -gencode arch=compute_37,code=sm_37 -gencode arch=compute_50,code=sm_50 -gencode arch=compute_52,code=sm_52 -gencode arch=compute_60,code=sm_60 -gencode arch=compute_61,code=sm_61 -gencode arch=compute_70,code=sm_70 -gencode arch=compute_75,code=sm_75 -gencode arch=compute_80,code=sm_80 -gencode arch=compute_86,code=sm_86 -gencode arch=compute_86,code=compute_86 -o simpleDeviceLibrary.o -c simpleDeviceLibrary.cu
nvcc fatal   : Unknown option '--threads'
make[1]: *** [Makefile:321: simpleDeviceLibrary.o] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/user/NVIDIA_CUDA-11.3_Samples/0_Simple/simpleSeparateCompilation'
make: *** [Makefile:51: 0_Simple/simpleSeparateCompilation/Makefile.ph_build] Error 2
```

Comment: It looks like you are not using nvcc from the CUDA 11.3 toolkit. The `threads` option was only added to nvcc during the CUDA 11.2 release cycle. If it doesn't recognize the option, you are using an older version to build newer samples

Comment: @talonmies I found that issue on google but I am using nvcc from 11.3 I guess. nvcc--version gives me this output 

nvcc: NVIDIA (R) Cuda compiler driver
Copyright (c) 2005-2021 NVIDIA Corporation
Built on Mon_May__3_19:15:13_PDT_2021
Cuda compilation tools, release 11.3, V11.3.109
Build cuda_11.3.r11.3/compiler.29920130_0

Comment: Are you really sure that `/usr/local/cuda/bin/nvcc` is CUDA 11.3? What the makefile finds and what your shell finds may not be the same thing

Comment: @talonmies oh, my bad. I had updated the /usr/local/cuda symlink to point to /usr/local/cuda-11.3 but somehow it was still pointing to /usr/local/cuda-11.1 only. solved the issue, now. thanks.

Comment: I have added a short community wiki answer for future visitors that make the same mistake. I would appreciate it if you would accept it to make it more visible in search

Comment: The exact issue was, I had run "sudo ln -s ..." to update the existing link. and while doing "ls -l /usr/local/cuda" was showing to pointing to /usr/local/cuda-11.3 but when I listed content under /usr/local/cuda I found that it was in the directory of cuda 11.1. So, I first removed the link then recreated it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `--threads` option (which controls the number of threads which `nvcc` will attempt to spawn during compilation) was only added to `nvcc` 11.3.

The OP was unwittingly using `nvcc` 11.1 to try and compile samples from the CUDA 11.3 toolkit using the supplied Makefiles, which include this option. This resulted in an unrecognized option error and build failure.

If you have this problem, double check that your compiler is new enough to accept this compiler option and that search paths/symlinks/modulefiles etc. are really updated to point to that compiler version.